# How to know if you have a jQuery object

Tags: jquery

Two questions really...

Firstly, which is the better coding style when writing jQuery functions which take object params, should the function take a jQuery object or is it better to pass a standard JavaScript object and have the function itself do the wrapping? I guess I'm just asking if there is a standard here, since it might not always be obvious to someone who wants to call the function.

And secondly, how do you test if an object is a jQuery object? Ideally it would be nice if the function could take either, so...

```
function(obj) {
    var $obj;
    if (isJQuery(obj)) {
        $obj = obj;
    }
    else {
        $obj = $(obj);
    }
    // ....
}
```

or do you even need to do this? will `$(obj)` simply return if the object is already a jQuery object, so you can always attempt to wrap and it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can test for the [`.jquery` property](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L195) (which is on the prototype of jQuery objects), like this:

```
function(obj) {
  var $obj = obj.jquery ? obj : $(obj);
}
```

This is what [jQuery core does internally as well](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L168).

---

**Update:** [My ticket filed as a result of this question](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7200) was completed, you can now find [the `.jquery` property in the official API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/.jquery/).

---

<s>*Edit:* as @[T.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) points out in comments this *isn't* currently in [the official API](http://api.jquery.com/), however [it's been around since jQuery 1.0](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.0/src/jquery/jquery.js#L88) and I'm pretty sure it isn't going anywhere.</s>  All the same based on comment discussions (thanks T.J.), I submitted an enhancement ticket to hopefully get this added to the API documentation, you can track its progress here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7200

Comment: I can totally see why jQuery does that (to play nice cross-window), but I'd use `instanceof` in my own application (rather than library) code, just because it's so standard whereas the `.jquery` property is undocumented and could change in a dot release.

Comment: @TJCrowder - I *highly* doubt it's going to change, it's how jQuery does their versioning.  Why not go with what always works?  This goes back to version 1.0: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.0/src/jquery/jquery.js#L88

Comment: @Nick: See my response to you on the other answer. Frankly, they should document it. Just because something hasn't changed doesn't mean it won't. Relying on undocumented features is almost always a bad idea and one's knee-jerk reaction should be not to. I'm not saying one never does it, and I'm not saying I won't use the above in cross-window situations, just that one should be reluctant to rely on undocumented things when there's a simple, viable alternative.

Comment: @TJCrowder - That's not a bad suggestion at all, I'll put in a jQuery ticket later today to see if it can be added to the documented API.  To be clear though, you're making *assumptions* as to what's viable, it really depends on the situation.

Comment: @Nick: :-) I was thinking of doing the same, I'll leave it to you.

Comment: @TJCrowder - Added to the bug tracker as an enhancement, you can monitor it here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7200

Comment: @Nick: And as soon as I saw the new `jQuery.type` function in the 1.4.3 API, I added this one: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7224 :-)

Comment: @TJCrowder - Not to shoot you down early, but I think that it will and should be rejected...think of the side-effects, for this *one* case you'd make everyone do a `if(jQuery.type(obj) =="object" || jQuery.type(obj) == "jQuery")` (or some variant).  I for one wouldn't be in favor of this at all...it would affect two dozen places in my code already.  Also for cross-window situations what would *it* be checking....my guess is `.jquery` :)

Comment: @T.J. - Just as an update, [my request](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7200) went through, this is now [part of the official API](http://api.jquery.com/.jquery/).

Comment: @Nick: Yeah, I saw that. Good deal. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I would think something along these lines:

```
    if (obj instanceof jQuery) {
        $obj = obj;
    }
    else {
        $obj = $(obj);
    }
```

> will `$(obj)` simply return if the object is already a jQuery object, so you can always attempt to wrap and it doesn't matter?

Well, it returns a **clone** of the jQuery object that you pass (see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#cloning-jquery-objects)). This may probably result in unintended behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why this is so much less modded-up than Nick's answer. This is using normal, straightforward JavaScript structure.

Comment: That said, you might want to mention that it will only work with jQuery instances created by the `jQuery` function *you* have. If you receive an object from another window (not uncommon), it may be a jQuery instance from the `jQuery` function in *that* window, in which case `instanceof` will be `false` (because you're testing against the wrong function). But for the vast majority of people not writing libraries and such, this is an edge case.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: After reading your explanation, I would think Nick's answer got more upvotes because it's more reliable than `instanceof`, *and* OP is intending to write a library/function anyway. Didn't realize the cross-window issues though.

Comment: @BoltClock: Depends on your definition of "reliable." :-) Nick's relies on an undocumented aspect of jQuery that could change in a dot release (1.4.2 to 1.4.3, for example). I don't like doing that unless I have a *really* good reason to. Unless you're writing a library, or an application where you specifically know you're dealing with cross-window issues, there's no need.

Comment: @TJCrowder - I have to disagree here, it's never changed, [has existed from the beginning](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.0/src/jquery/jquery.js#L89) and *many* things use this, it's not going anywhere, why would it?  It's their *only* versioning mechanism, the same way the UI team adapted later.  Also just to note, this doesn't work in a number of `jQuery.noConflict(true)` scenarios as well.

Comment: @Nick: Fair enough, we'll disagree. :-) I'm very glad to know about it for those cross-windows situations. I think they should document it, frankly. Re `noConflict`: Compare it against your reference for jQuery, that's the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: FYI, this is what I mean about the `noConflict` symbol: http://jsbin.com/iyeje4